# R: Color attribute in a multiplex-network

Tags: r, tidyverse, networkx, igraph

I have the following fake dataframe of a directed social network. Each node in `from` does belong to a specific `cluster` (A, B, C, D, E).

```r
library(igraph)
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
library(tidyverse)
library(network)
library(sna)
library(intergraph)

# fake dataframe (on edges-level)
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(from = sample(LETTERS, size = 20, replace = TRUE),
                 to = sample(LETTERS, size = 20, replace = TRUE))

# cluster-definition on node-level (edited)
clusters <- data.frame(from = LETTERS) %>%
mutate(cluster = 1,
cluster = ifelse(from %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 2, cluster),
cluster = ifelse(from %in% c("E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), 3, cluster))


df2 <- df %>% filter(from != to)  # no self-loops
```

Then, I want to plot the network and color the nodes according to the `cluster` they belong to.

```r
# Create graph
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df2, directed = TRUE)
V(g)$cluster <- df2$cluster

# plot network
ggnet2(simplify(g), node.color = V(g)$cluster) # doesn't work
```

My problem is, that when I use set.seed(2) the network is not multiplex and the code works fine, but if I use set.seed(3) for example, `V(g)$cluster <- df2$cluster` raises problems:

```r
Error in i_set_vertex_attr(x, attr(value, "name"), index = value, value = attr(value,  : 
  Length of new attribute value must be 1 or 21, the number of target vertices, not 18
```

I think this is because `simplify(g)` reduces the number of nodes, so that the number of nodes is smaller than the length of `df2$cluster`.

Of course I could just use sed.seed(2) in this example, but my **real** network seems to be multiplex.

Unfortunately, I have no idea, how I could solve this problem. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

At least as far as this simulation goes, you seem to be setting cluster by edge rather than node. Does something like this help?

```
library(igraph)

gen_net <- function(nedges) {
    df <- data.frame(
        from = sample(LETTERS, size = nedges, replace = TRUE),
        to = sample(LETTERS, size = nedges, replace = TRUE)
    )

    df2 <- df[which(df$from != df$to), ]
    
    nodes <- unique(unlist(df2))
    nnodes <- length(nodes)
    clusters <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], nnodes, replace = TRUE)

    g <- graph_from_data_frame(df2, directed = TRUE)
    V(g)$cluster <- clusters
    V(g)$color <- sapply(V(g)$cluster, function(i) grep(i, LETTERS))

    return(g)
}

set.seed(2)
g <- gen_net(20)
plot(g)

set.seed(3)
g <- gen_net(20)
plot(g)
```

### Edit

You should still be fine if you already have community membership. Below I make a random graph, but I find the communities with `cluster_walktrap()` and treat those as given. In the plot, community membership is shown by node color and the multi-edges are emphasized with thicker, darker lines.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)

N <- 100
m <- 2
p <- .1

g <- sample_pa(N, m = m, start.graph = make_star(3))
h <- sample_pa(N, m = m, start.graph = make_star(3))

G <- disjoint_union(g, h)

rewire <- function(G) {
    nodes <- as.numeric(V(G))
    edges <- ends(G, es = E(G))
    rns <- runif(nrow(edges))
    newtails <- ifelse(rns < p, sample(nodes, 1), edges[, 2])
    graph_from_edgelist(cbind(edges[, 1], newtails))
}

S <- rewire(G) # this graph has multi-edges in it

clusters <- cluster_walktrap(S)
V(S)$color <- membership(clusters)
E(S)$color <- ifelse(which_multiple(S), "black", "gray60")
E(S)$width <- ifelse(which_multiple(S), 2, 1)
dev.new(height = 10, width = 10)
plot(S, vertex.label = "", vertex.size = 3, edge.arrow.size = 0.5)
```

Comment: Well, thanks for that! Unfortunately, my aim is not to create a random cluster-variable afterwardss and use it then for coloring the edges (I was just generating clusters randomly for the sake of the example). In my real data the clusters are already given right from the beginning (so in `gen_net()`). I hope, you understand my point.

Comment: Definitely. I've updated my answer with a different sim. Does it get closer to what you need?

Comment: tbh, no :( why can't we just start from my original fake dataset with 3 columns `from`, `to`, and `cluster` and simply plot them with colors according to the cluster-variable? I'm no igraph-expert and there's no need to calculate the clusters again (as they are already given in my dataset). It is actually a network of documents that contain links to other documents. the clusters I calculated using different cluster methods such as hierarchical or kmeans-clustering. anyway thanks for your effort!

Comment: Argh! Well, in your fake dataset, when the seed is 3, you have 18 edges and 21 nodes. That's why you can't set values for `V(g)$cluster` with `df2$cluster`: the lengths are different. `df2` is an edge list, so `cluster` is being defined on the edges instead of the nodes.

Comment: But how could I then define cluster as an attribute of the nodes instead? Actually, `cluster` was meant to be linked to the nodes in the `from`-column. The clusters come from another dataframe originally and were just joined. So  if a letter appears repeatedly in the column `from` the `cluster` should always be identical (in the real data).

Comment: I have adjusted to entry post now, so that `cluster` depends on `from` (and is not at random).

Answer (score 0):

**First,  build a reproducible example.**

```
library(igraph)

## Reproducible example in R Base.
## Note: vertex attribute name has a special meaning.
## Calculate both edges and vertices.
## Cluster id. in separate data frame.
set.seed(2)

edges <- data.frame(from = sample(LETTERS, size = 20, replace = TRUE),
                      to = sample(LETTERS, size = 20, replace = TRUE))

clusters <- data.frame(from = LETTERS, cluster = 1)
clusters[clusters$from %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D"),"cluster"]            <- 2
clusters[clusters$from %in% c("E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), "cluster"] <- 3

## Calculate vertices and assign cluster no. using merge.
vtxids <- sort(union(edges$from, edges$to))
vt1    <- data.frame(name = vtxids)
vtx    <- merge(x = vt1, y = clusters, by.x = "name", by.y = "from", all.x = TRUE)

## or alternatively use match (faster).
vtx <- vt1; vtx$cluster <- clusters[match(vtx$name, clusters$from),"cluster"]   

## Some defensive coding.
orphans <- vtx$name[is.na(vtx$cluster)]
if (length(orphans) > 0L) warning("Vertices without cluster: ", orphans)

## create graph and remove loops, multiple edges, and isolates.
g  <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, vertices=vtx, directed = TRUE)
g2 <- simplify(g)
g3 <- delete.vertices(g2 , which(degree(g2)==0))
g3
```

**Then plot.**

```
## Use default palette.
dev.new(); plot(g3, vertex.color=vtx$cluster)

## Or.
V(g3)$color <- V(g3)$cluster
dev.new(); plot(g3)

## Or palette supplied by igraph.
colors <- heat.colors(length(unique(vtx$cluster)))
vtx_color <- colors[vtx$cluster]
dev.new(); plot(g3, vertex.color=vtx_color)
```